# How to get account name of current action?

Tags: smart-contract, action, wallet, account-name

I am gonna get account name of caller(wallet) in my action of smart contract.
I used functions current_receiver(), get_sender(), get_first_receiver().
but I got contract`s account name and empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check/verify authorization of an account, pass the account-name as an argument to your ACTION and call require_auth(...) or has_auth(...).

```
void test::test(name user) {
   check(has_auth(user), "User not authorized");
   ...
}


void test::test(name user) {
   require_auth(user);
   ...
}
```